# hasManyThrough with two intermediate tables (so three joins)?

Tags: laravel

The hasManyThrough relationship allows you to effectively query with two table joins.

I have four tables in a hierarchy, so the ultimate parent, to access its great-grand-children, needs to do three joins.

Is there any support for a hasManyThrough with two intermediate tables?

Just wondering...

Comment: I don't think that's possible with hasManyThrough. You could always just create a query scope and use `JOIN`s yourself.

Comment: There is no native relationship for this case. I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with unlimited levels: [`HasManyDeep`](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

Comment: Looking back at this question, I found a solution for my app in a different way, which was to denormalise so that the items at the bottom of my hierarchy held a key to the ultimate parent instead, without having to query up the chain via two or more joins. Remembering to keep these duplicate keys updated in both places if ever changed (turns out they aren't (almost) ever changed in my case), the decision to cautiously denormalise in this way seems to has served me well. Interesting to explore though, and will take a look at your package...   :)  thanks.